# PHP - "&" character gets hidden in $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, urlencode

I am using a custom PHP file to send data to my JSON file and update it, but if an '&' character is into a string, that string gets truncated and the text after that '&? char gets hidden, as well as the '&'.

**m-add-edit.php**:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
$tableName = $_POST['tableName'];

// HTML sanitization
if (strpos($tableName, '<') !== false || strpos($tableName, '>') !== false
){ $tableName = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $tableName); }

// Get JSON Table's Data
$data = file_get_contents($tableName. '.json');
$data_array = json_decode($data, true);

// SAVE DATA
$newDataArr = array();

foreach ($data_array[0] as $k=>$v){
    $keysArr = explode("_", $k);
    $kType = $keysArr[0];
    $kName = $keysArr[1];

    echo $_POST[$k]; // This is just to test the output when sending data
}
```

Following is the AJAX function I use to get values from an input field (`#itemDescription`) and call the PHP file above:

```
var params = 'tableName=Items&description='+ $('#itemDescription').val();

    $.ajax({
        url : 'm-add-edit.php?',
        type: 'POST',
        data: params,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); // <-- JUST TO TEST THE OUTPUT
    
        // error
        }, error: function(e) {  
    }});
```

So, if the `#itemDescription` input contains a '&' character, that gets hidden, and the text after it too.

[image]

The console log I get is:

```
Text with
```

Is there a way to make '&' character recognizable as any other character and avoid my text to be truncated?

Comment: You've logged everything but the content you're sending to the server... Nothing suspicious in `tableName=Items&description=Text with & and more` ?

Comment: Franko why don't you use PHP's builtin sanitization?

Comment: @sxkx how to use that in my PHP code?

Comment: Please share more details - if "and more" is printed, what makes you think that anything got "hidden"?

Comment: @NicoHaase the console log and screenshot show it clearly, I get only "Text with", not "Text with & and more". What should I say more?

Comment: What have yout ried to debug the problem? Is the request sent properly (which you could check in your browser's network console)? What is the content of `$_POST` if you dump it as the very first thing in your PHP script? Does it containt the full string?

Comment: Additionally, what **exactly** does `params` include on sending? `tableName=Items&description=Text with & and more`? How should PHP guess that the `&`in the middle is **not** a seperator between values, but part of that value? Why not use an array of parameters, and let jQuery handle all the escaping? If you don't want to use an array for this, you need to handle special chars on your own (as noted by Andreas in the very first comment!)

Comment: @NicoHaase good point, I'll see what I can do, thanks.

Comment: If you replace `$tableName = $_POST['tableName'];` with `$tableName = filter_var($_POST['tableName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` you can do away with the `// HTML sanitization` section. For information see; [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and [Sanitize filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).

Comment: That said (my previous comment), you should still validate the `tableName` to make sure it has a valid format. PHP sanitization just encodes dangerous characters, it does not strip them (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're sending your data in a URL encoded string where the ampersand character has a special meaning and needs to be encoded.

However, with a POST request you should pass the values in the body of the request, not the URL. The simplest way to do this with jQuery is to provide an object to the `data` property of the `$.ajax` settings instead, and jQuery will take care of encoding it correctly and setting it in the right part of the request for you.

In addition, you should remove the `async: false` setting. Always send AJAX requests asynchronously as synchronous requests are deprecated and will display a warning in the browser console. As you're using callbacks correctly, you don't need `async: false` anyway.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'm-add-edit.php?',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    tableName: 'Items',
    description: $('#itemDescription').val()
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(x, s, e) {
    console.log(x, s, e);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that it’s dynamic data, i need to set a parameters string as ‘data’, because i use also mobile sdk to call that ajax function

Comment: This answer will still work for that case. It's logically identical to what you already had, I have only changed how the data is provided to the AJAX request

Comment: Ok, thanks so much, so I understood the '&' issue, the problem is that I have no idea about how to build an array to pass to my AJAX function and make it work properly with my m-add-edit.php file. I'll search for something about it

Comment: What keeps you from using the code posted? Map `params = 'tableName=Items&description='+ $('#itemDescription').val();` to `params = {tableName: 'Items', description: [...] }` and you're done

Answer (score 0):

the equivalent of encodeUri in php:  using [rawurlencode](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode)

```
function encodeURIComponent($str) {
    $revert = array('%21'=>'!', '%26' =>'&', '%2A'=>'*', '%27'=>"'", '%28'=>'(', '%29'=>')');
    return strtr(rawurlencode($str), $revert);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your function, but for some reason, it doesn't work, I have an Ubuntu server on AWS, I don't know if that's the problem

Comment: This won't work if the AJAX request sends the data in the wrong format

Comment: in fact the problem is your server..your server should be decode correctly the url

Comment: No, the problem is that the AJAX request sends the data unencoded

Comment: @NicoHaase is right, it's because I'm passing a URL string like "tablename=table&string=text&more&other=blabla" etc. So AJAX cannot understand what & is about and 'thinks' that & is a separator

Comment: yes i understand that, i am using encodeUri just for `text&more&other=blabla` with $.Post, and this type is ok for me ..i have never used $ajax, i am surprise $.ajax doesnt do the same result than $.POST..or i missunderstand something

Answer (score -1):

If you have a problem with specific sign, why don't use some replace functions and change `&` to other specific and original signs e.g.: `_ampersand_` or something similar to this, and after send decodes it.

Comment: how to do that, in my case?

Comment: See Frenchy's post, he says exacly what I mean.

Comment: Don't do this manually. Don't fiddle around with replacing something to magic strings which you need to map in the opposite direction in PHP - what if your content would contain `_ampersand_` in the cleartext?

Comment: That's why I wrote the "specific and original" one, I don't see any difference between the built-in method and my own, and that `_ampersand_` was only a simple example.